# perl line count a file containing a specific text

Tags: perl, parameters, line-count

Basically I want to count the number if lines which contain the word Out.

```
my $lc1 = 0;
open my $file, "<", "LNP_Define.cfg" or die($!);
#return [ grep m|Out|, <$file> ]; (I tried something with return to but also failed)
#$lc1++ while <$file>;
#while <$file> {$lc1++ if (the idea of the if statement is to count lines if it contains  Out)
close $file;
print $lc1, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The command line might be potential option for you too:

```
perl -ne '$lc1++ if /Out/; END { print "$lc1\n"; } ' LNP_Define.cfg
```

The **-n** assumes a **while** loop for all your code before **END**.
The **-e** expects code surrounded by **' '**.

The **$lc1++** will count only if the following if statement is true.

The **if** statement runs per line looking for "*Out*".

The **END { }** statement is for processing after the while loops ends. Here is where you can print the count.

**Or without the command line:**

```
my $lc1;
while ( readline ) {
    $lc1++ if /Out/; 
}    
print "$lc1\n";
```

**Then run on the command line:**

```
$ perl count.pl LNP_Define.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `index`:

```
0 <= index $_, 'Out' and $lc1++ while <$file>;
```

Comment: personally I would be more comfortable with parentheses bracing index parameters, and preceding `0` in comparison

Comment: choroba can you please explain exactly what that line is doing? Thank you.

Comment: @dsaliba: it searches for 'Out' in each line. If it is found somewhere (index returns the position, i.e. 0 or more), $lc1 is incremented.